# Unresolved Error while using stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load function

Tags: stb-image

I get unresolved symbol error while using stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load function.

I have added the #include <stb_image.h> file as header , do i need to do something else also ?

stb_image - v2.19

```
#include <stb_image.h>

stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // this gives unresolved symbol error though
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to compile stb_image. This should work:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
```